# How do I find a user using DirectoryServices AccountManagement?

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryservices

I've used DirectoryEntry & DirectorySearcher for quite some time and it always works.  Recently I learned about AccountManagement and thought I'd try it for a new project.  But I can't get it to find me.

This old code work fine:

```
Using oDirectoryEntry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://us.psy.com", "xxx2yyy", "MyStrongPwd")
    Using oDirectorySearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(oDirectoryEntry)
        oDirectorySearcher.Filter = "(&(sAMAccountType=805306368)(sAMAccountName=xxx2yyy))"
        Try
            Return oDirectorySearcher.FindOne IsNot Nothing
        Catch
            Return False
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

But I cannot make this work:

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "US", "DC=psy,DC=com"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(context.ConnectedServer); // This shows me the server name
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "xxx2yyy"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(user.SamAccountName); // results in Object reference not set to an instance of an object
        user.ChangePassword("OldPwd", "NewPwd");
        user.Save();
    }
}
```

Hoping someone can see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Code seems fine to me - must be something more subtle.... could you try to **(1)** use `UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current` to just the get currently logged in user, and **(2)** use `PrincipalSearcher.FindAll()` to see if you can enumerate the users in that AD container? Do these methods work? Or provide a meaningful, helpful error, possibly?

Comment: The second point I'd check is whether you're using the correct container - the first example uses `LDAP://us.psy.com`, while your second example uses `DC=psy,DC=com` - maybe it needs to be `DC=us,DC=psy,DC=com` instead?

Comment: I tried your second point but it did not work.  The domain is "US" and the container is psy.com.  And it does show me the server name in the MessageBox so I know that part is working.  I'll try your first suggestion and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think marc_s is on the right track. But you can just specify the domain the same way you do with `DirectoryEntry`. You can use the constructor with [only the domain name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_PrincipalContext__ctor_System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_ContextType_System_String_), like this:

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "us.psy.com"))
```

That will search your whole domain.

That said, if you already know how to use `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher`, you're better off sticking with it. The `AccountManagement` namespace is just uses them in the background anyway. It *can* make some things easier, but it hides a lot from you, which hurts performance. Using `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher` directly will almost always perform faster.

I talked a bit about that in an article I wrote (but also how to get better performance from `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher`): [Active Directory: Better Performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I did. I had to get it done so I just went back to what I knew.  I tried to use AccountManagement because of articles I read saying how great it was.